# I am not able to create parquet tables by default in Apache Spark 2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am trying to create parquet tables in Spark without using `Stored as parquet` flag. In other words, I want to create them as parquet by default, but It seems parquet is not the default format in Spark.

For example, by using the following code, I would like to create a parquet table.

```
spark.sql(""" CREATE external table schema.table_a(id STRING, text STRING) LOCATION 'path_to_the tables' """)
```

On the other hand, I was able to achieve the requirement in Hive, using the flag `hive.default.fileformat=parquet`.

I'm using EMR 5.32 and I tried to set `hive.default.fileformat=parquet` on the spark-defaults classification.

Is there any flag that can help me achieve my goal?

Comment: how about creating an empty dataframe with proper schema and `df.write.format('parquet').saveAsTable('schema.table_a')` ?

Comment: I want to create the table in parquet without specifying I need it in parquet, I want that behaviour as default. I could achieve that in hive by using `hive.default.fileformat=parquet`

Comment: if you run `df.write.saveAsTable('schema.table_a')`, what format would it create?

Comment: If i do ``` elem = spark.sql("SET hive.default.fileformat")
elem.show(20, False) ``` I see the parameter as undefined, even if I set the parameter in spark-defaults file, the parameter is still undefined.

Comment: I meant, if you run this `df.write.saveAsTable('schema.table_a')`, what format would it create? ORC or parquet?

Comment: I am not able to create the tables in parquet by default because for some reason, I cannot set **hive.default.fileformat** and **hive.default.fileformat.managed** variables from any EMR classification(spark-hive-site and spark-defaults).
If I set the variables manually when the cluster is up, the persistence works, but that is not the behaviour we want to. I mean, what we need is to set those variables in the EMR template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem, when calling spark-sql command I passed hive variables using **--hiveconf** for each flag I want to bypass.
I was using **--conf** flag for passing hive variables, but **--conf** flag is for spark flags, not hive.

Answer (score 0):

Try `spark.sql.sources.default=parquet` [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) It should be parquet by default, but maybe something override it on your end.

Comment: Nothing, `spark.sql.sources.default` is already parquet as you said. The strange thing here is that if I do `
spark.sql("SET hive.default.fileformat=parquet")` before creating the tables, the result is what I expected, but I don't want to add a line setting a global variable, instead, I want that behaviour as default.